# how to fix error: not a statement with += on an array

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am attempting to create a Mean Absolute Deviation calculator, with a user-defined number of entries, which I accomplished with an array, adding elements in a for loop. The actual calculation is set up correctly, but i keep getting an error while compiling.

I have tried stating the variable and then using the += operator, only to receive 4 errors for each of the for loops. It simply says- error: not a statement. the error is specifically in distances[bruh] right on the opening of [].

```
for(int bruh2 = 0; bruh2 < ude; bruh2++){
    double halfofmean1 += points[bruh2];
```

I would like to see halfofmean1 be set to the sum of all elements in the points array(which is a double array), but it keeps showing errors while compiling.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you meant to sum the elements in `points` with your loop, to do so you must declare and initialize `halfofmean1` **before** the loop. Like,

```
double halfofmean1 = 0;
for(int bruh2 = 0; bruh2 < ude; bruh2++){
    halfofmean1 += points[bruh2];
}
```

If you're using Java 8+, you could use a `DoubleStream` to sum the `points` like

```
double halfofmean1 = Arrays.stream(points).sum();
```

Comment: Thank you, before i predefined the halfofmean1 double inside the for loop. Will try and get back to you.

Comment: alright, the first one didnt work. trying the second solution now.

Comment: not exactly sure what a DoubleStream is. could you clarify as to whether i need to format that to fit my code?

Comment: Here's what i got:

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
    double halfofmean1 = Arrays.stream(points).sum(); the carat is just under the A in Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing here, but shouldn't halfOfMean be declared before the loop (and initialized to zero)?